# Player not showing up on canvas (Javascript + html + css)

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have a file called index.html that I am putting an html5 game on. All I have done so far is created a canvas,

```
<canvas id="mainCanvas"></canvas>
```

that is 25% of the browser's width, and 400px tall.

```
canvas {
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 25%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Then I made the script tag inside it, and connected my canvas to it, then added context.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var context = document.getElementById("2d");
```

Now I have a player variable.

```
var player = {
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        width: 30,
        height: 30
};
```

then I have a setInterval function that runs a function called game that runs two functions named update and render.

```
    function game() {
        update();
        render();
    }

    function update() {

    }

    function render() {
        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        game();
    }, 1000/30);
```

As you can see, I made a rectangle with the player. Why is it not showing up? The rectangle is not appearing on the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Typo :**

In order to call the canvas context, you need to use [`canvas.getContext('2d')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) instead of `getElementById()`